# Unable to pass slice of interface to blank interface type function

Tags: go

I am using "garyburd/redigo/redis" in my goLang application and trying to make subscription to multiple channels using `pubSubConn.Subscribe()`
Passing values like `pubSubConn.Subscribe("chn1", "chn2")` works and creates subscription to two channels but I don't know how to pass n channels in this function. I have tried passing slice of interface, but it converts it to string

```
var anything []interface{}
    var stringList []string
    stringList = append(stringList, "chn1")
    stringList = append(stringList, "chn2")
    for _, val := range stringList {
    anything = append(anything, val)
}
```

But output is subscription to one channel "[chn1 chn2]"

Please help.

Comment: This code is fine (albeit convoluted). The issue is almost certainly that you don't pass separate arguments to Subscribe `Subscribe(anything)` instead of `Subscribe(anything...)`.

Comment: ah, ok, thank you! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

```
var stringList []string
stringList = append(stringList, "chn1")
stringList = append(stringList, "chn2")

pubSubConn.Subscribe(stringList...)
```

more https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters